# C-get specific input from user

Tags: c, stdin

I need to get some specific input from user(user needs to enter "init 3 4 NORTH", 3 is value of X(int type), 4 is the value of Y(int type),NORTH is the value of direction(enum type) init is the command which they must enter it.) if user just enter "3 4 NORTH", the program will not do anything.

I am not allowing to use any scanf family to get input.

This is what I have implemented so far:

```
char input[10];
printf("Enter the command...\n");
if(fgets(input,sizeof(input),stdin)!= NULL){
     if(input[0]=='i' && input[1]=='n' && input[2]=='i' && input[3]=='t'){
        int x=atoi(&input[5]);
        int y=atoi(&input[7]);
         //doing similar things for Direction value.....
       }
     }
```

so that is my idea to check the first value "init", and get two int values, get the direction value.
I am hoping my explanation is clear enough, hope anyone can share their ideas.

Comment: Firstly, `strncmp` http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strcmp.3.html will help you...

Comment: `sscanf` will also help you.

Comment: You do not want to use `scanf`, what about `sscanf`?

Comment: the input buffer is too small.

Comment: "init 3 4 NORTH" is `{'i','n','i','t',' ','3','4',' ','N','O','R','T','H','\0'}` which is, as you can see, larger then the 10 chars your input buffer holds.

Comment: If a user is inputting a line of text STOP COUNTING CHARS.  Declare buffers as [256].  Don't mess about with [10] or any other small value, (unless you are on a RAM-restricted embedded environment).

Comment: thanks for pointing out the char number, i didn't realize it until you guys tell me. I will fix in the real program.

Comment: Nice one, so i can use strncmp for checking the "init". But the other value, i still need to use like "int x=atoi(&input[5]);" right? @Morovaille

Comment: @JasonWang you have no guarantee the first word is 4 chars long. The best method, imho, is to implement a split function, which store every word in an array : from "init 3 4 NORTH" to ["init", "3", "4", "NORTH", NULL] (for example). And then you can process the words easily.

Comment: @Morovaille i had that idea as well, but i don't how to achieve that by using fgets, i can do it by using scanf. Is the function like this(loop until there is a space, then save the value into arrary, then loop again to find the next space.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void) {
    char input[256];
    printf("Enter the command...\n");
    if(fgets(input,sizeof(input),stdin) != NULL) {
        char    *tok;
        if ((tok = strtok(input, " ")) != NULL) {
            if (strcmp(tok, "init") != 0)
                ;//error
        }
        else
            ;//error
        if ((tok = strtok(NULL, " ")) != NULL) {
            /*Check first number and process it */
        }
        else
            ;//error
        if ((tok = strtok(NULL, " ")) != NULL) {
            /*Check second number and process it */
        }
        else
            ;//error
        if ((tok = strtok(NULL, " \n")) != NULL) {
            /*Check direction with strcmp */
        }
        else
            ;//error
    }
}
```

Comment: This will not match a direction, unless you add `newline` to the delimiters. `strtok(NULL, " \n")`

Comment: @Morovaille that is the easiest way!

Answer (score 2):

One problem with your approach is that it won't work if the numbers are > 9. If you don't want to use `scanf` you can read the line with `fgets` and then use `sscanf` to extract its parts. Note the validity of the reading is checked even before the values themselves are examined.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void) {
    char line[256];
    char cmd[32];
    char dir[32];
    int x;
    int y;

    if(fgets(line, sizeof line, stdin) == NULL) {
        return 1;
    }
    if(sscanf(line, "%32s%d%d%32s", cmd, &x, &y , dir) != 4) {
        return 1;
    }

    // now check you got valid command, values, and direction
    if(strcmp(cmd, "init") != 0) {
        return 1;
    }
    if(x < 0 || x > 99 || y < 0 || y > 99) {
        return 1;
    }
    if(strcmp(dir, "NORTH") != 0) {
        return 1;
    }

    printf("Your command: %s %d %d %s\n", cmd, x, y, dir);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Hah, the program is just for a console game(9x9), so i don't need to get number more than 9. I am so sorry that i cannot use sscanf as well, my tutor wants us to learn how to use fgets since they said it is better than scanf and sscanf. But your approach is very good in real programming world, thanks for helping!

Comment: @Jason Wang in that case your question should have said "I am not allowed to use the `scanf` family of functions", but you said "it is not safe". This uses `fgets` and `sscanf` not `scanf`.

Answer (score 2):

Regardless how you approach this, you simply need to take it step-by-step sequentially, and validate each portion of the needed `init DIRECTION X Y` input you get from the user. Not being able to use the `scanf` family, isn't a problem, you will just have to rely on pointers and index arithmetic.

One approach in that regard is to *walk a pointer* down your input string comparing values as you go. There are many ways to do this, but one approach is the following:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAXC 256

void help() { printf (" format 'init DIRECTION X Y'\n"); }

int main (void) {

    enum { EAST, NORTH, WEST, SOUTH } dir;
    char *names[] = { "EAST", "NORTH", "WEST", "SOUTH" };
    char input[MAXC] = "";
    char *init = "init";
    int x, y;

    for (;;) {
        char *p, *ep = NULL;
        printf ("Enter the commmand: ");
        fgets (input, MAXC, stdin);
        if (strncmp (input, init, strlen (init))) { /* compare 'init' 1st */
            help(); continue;
        }
        if (!(p = strchr (input, ' ') + 1)) {   /* find 1st space */
            help(); continue;
        }   /* locate 'N', 'S', 'E', 'W' */
        while (*p && *p != 'E' && *p != 'N' && *p != 'W' && *p != 'S') p++;
        if (!*p || !(ep = strchr (p, ' '))) {   /* find following space */
            help(); continue;
        }
        *ep = 0;        /* nul-terminate */
        switch (*p) {   /* test cardinal names */
            case 'E' : if (strcmp (p, "EAST")) { help(); continue; }
                    else dir = EAST;
                    break;
            case 'N' : if (strcmp (p, "NORTH")) { help(); continue; }
                    else dir = NORTH; 
                    break;
            case 'W' : if (strcmp (p, "WEST")) { help(); continue; }
                    else dir = WEST;
                    break;
            case 'S' : if (strcmp (p, "SOUTH")) { help(); continue; }
                    else dir = SOUTH; 
                    break;
            default : help(); continue;
        }
        *ep = ' ';      /* restore space */
        p = ep + 1;     /* advance to next char */
        while (*p && (*p < '0' || '9' < *p)) p++;   /* find digit */
        if (!*p) {
            help(); continue;
        }
        x = *p++ - '0'; /* set x value -- single digit conversion */
        while (*p && (*p < '0' || '9' < *p)) p++;   /* find digit */
        if (!*p) {
            help(); continue;
        }
        y = *p - '0';   /* set y value -- single digit conversion */
        break;          /* made it! break out of loop */
    }

    printf ("\n direction '%s', x '%d', y '%d'\n\n", names[dir], x, y);

    return 0;
}
```

When your input does not satisfy your requirements, it is helpful to give the user a bit of `help()` reminding them of the proper format, so they do not endlessly look at a blinking cursor wondering how in the heck to solve the puzzle.

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/direction
Enter the commmand: dog food
 format 'init DIRECTION X Y'
Enter the commmand: inid NORTH 3 6
 format 'init DIRECTION X Y'
Enter the commmand: init EASY 4 5
 format 'init DIRECTION X Y'
Enter the commmand: init EAST a 6
 format 'init DIRECTION X Y'
Enter the commmand: init WEST 6 b
 format 'init DIRECTION X Y'
Enter the commmand: init SOUTH 4 8

 direction 'SOUTH', x '4', y '8'
```

There are additional validations you can add, but this is a start to get you going.

Answer (score 1):

Since you cannot use scanf you should parse the input manually, quite straightforward.

```
void getcommand ()
{
    /*Extra byte for null termination*/
    char input[BUFFER_SIZE+1];
    char keyword[BUFFER_SIZE+1];
    char command[BUFFER_SIZE+1];
    int x=0;
    int y=0;
    char direction[BUFFER_SIZE+1];
    printf("Enter the command...\n");
    if(fgets(input,sizeof(input),stdin)!= NULL){
        /*find the first space*/
        int index=0;
        int i=0;
        for(; index<BUFFER_SIZE; ++index){
            if(input[index]==' '){
                break;
            }
        }
        /*Get the keyword*/
        for(; i<index; ++i){
            keyword[i]=input[i];
        }
        /*set null termination*/
        keyword[index]=0;
        /*Test valid keyword*/
        if(strcmp(keyword, "init")!=0){
            return;
        }
        /*save the command*/
        strcpy_s(command, sizeof(command),keyword);
        /*skip the current space*/
        ++index;
        ++i;
        /*find the next space*/
        for(; index<BUFFER_SIZE; ++index){
            if(input[index]==' '){
                break;
            }
        }
        /*Get the keyword*/
        int j=0;
        for(; i<index; ++j, ++i){
            keyword[j]=input[i];
        }
        /*add the null termination*/
        keyword[j]=0;
        /*Get the coordinate*/
        int x=atoi(keyword);
        /*skip the current space*/
        ++index;
        ++i;
        /*find the next space*/
        for(; index<BUFFER_SIZE; ++index){
            if(input[index]==' '){
                break;
            }
        }
        /*Get the keyword*/
        for(j=0; i<index; ++j, ++i){
            keyword[j]=input[i];
        }
        /*add the null termination*/
        keyword[j]=0;
        int y=atoi(keyword);
        /*skip the current space*/
        ++index;
        ++i;
        /*find the next space*/
        for(; index<BUFFER_SIZE; ++index){
            if(input[index]==' ' || input[index]=='\n'){
                break;
            }
        }
        /*Get the keyword*/
        for(j=0; i<index; ++j, ++i){
            keyword[j]=input[i];
        }
        /*add the null termination*/
        keyword[j]=0;
        /*Test valid keyword*/
        if(strcmp(keyword, "NORTH")==0){
            /*save the direction*/
            strcpy_s(direction, sizeof(command), keyword);
        }
        else if(strcmp(keyword, "SOUTH")==0){
            /*save the direction*/
            strcpy_s(direction, sizeof(command), keyword);
        }
        else if(strcmp(keyword, "EAST")==0){
            /*save the direction*/
            strcpy_s(direction, sizeof(command), keyword);
        }
        else if(strcmp(keyword, "WEST")==0){
            /*save the direction*/
            strcpy_s(direction, sizeof(command), keyword);
        }
        else{
            return;
        }
    }
    return;
}
```

It's a really important skill to learn so I encourage you to try it by yourself with other commands.

I hope that i've haven't use c++ syntax, I'm not used to write c code.